# Add space in RecyclerView with PagerSnapHelper

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, pagersnaphelper

I'm searching for a way to add a space between my items using a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView) and the [`PagerSnapHelper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PagerSnapHelper).

To demonstrate what I mean here is a gif:
[image]

As you can see above between the two images there is a little black space. But these space is only available **on scroll**. If the [scrollState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#getScrollState()) is in [`SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) the image get centered snapped and are "full width".

That is what I want to achieve.

My idea was to add a **new "placeholder" `viewType`** to my `RecyclerView.Adapter` and customize the `PagerSnapHelper` to "jump over" the **placeholder `viewType`** (to jump over each second `View` would be also possible).
But somehow this isn't working. I can't change the `PagerSnaperHelper` (or the `SnapHelper` with a lot of duplicated code from the `PagerSnapHelper`) to work like I want. Even further while implementing it felt somehow wrong. It felt like "this is not the way it should be".

So - any recommendations or ideas how I can solve this?
I'm totally open for all suggestions.

**Disclamer:**
I know I could use the old [`ViewPager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager) for this. But for special reasons I ask for an implementation for a `RecyclerView` . So please don't suggest to use the `ViewPager` here, thanks .

Comment: show here what have you  tried yet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:
Create two `viewType`, the first is your image, the second is a black indent. Then at `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` and `SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING` call `smoothScrollToPosition(position)` to the desired position.

```
val pagerSnapHelper = PagerSnapHelper()
val spacePagerSnapHelper = SpacePagerSnapHelper(pagerSnapHelper)
pagerSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
spacePagerSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
```

And this is the `SpacePagerSnapHelper`:

```
/**
 * This is an [RecyclerView.OnScrollListener] which will scrolls
 * the [RecyclerView] to the next closes position if the
 * position of the snapped View (calculated by the given [snapHelper] in [SnapHelper.findSnapView])
 * is odd. Because each odd position is a space/placeholder where we want to jump over.
 *
 * See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51747104).
 */
class SpacePagerSnapHelper(
        private val snapHelper: SnapHelper
) : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    private enum class ScrollDirection {
        UNKNOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
    }

    private var scrollDirection: ScrollDirection = UNKNOWN

    fun attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(this)
    }

    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        scrollDirection = if (dx > 0) RIGHT else LEFT
    }

    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        when (newState) {
            RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE -> onPageChanged(recyclerView)
            RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING -> onPageChanged(recyclerView)
        }
    }

    private fun onPageChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager
        val viewToSnap = snapHelper.findSnapView(layoutManager)
        viewToSnap?.let {
            val position = layoutManager.getPosition(it)
            // Only "jump over" each second item because it is a space/placeholder
            // see also MediaContentAdapter.
            if (position % 2 != 0) {
                when (scrollDirection) {
                    LEFT -> {
                        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position - 1)
                    }
                    RIGHT -> {
                        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position + 1)
                    }
                    UNKNOWN -> {
                        Timber.i("Unknown scrollDirection... Don't know where to go")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you [@UgAr0FF](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6184896/ugar0ff) that works like a charm ❤️. Currently only the "direction" is wrong (`recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position + 1)` could be also `- 1`). But I will update your answer later with my final solution. But thanks, that worked and is very smooth.

Answer (score 2):

UgAr0FF's solution generally works, but it also leads to unwanted scrolling behavior:

[how it shouldn't look](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzVGKX3TMsI)

As you can see, the PagerSnapHelper first tries to focus on the divider and then decides to move to the next item. I fixed the scrolling behavior so that it looks like this:

[how it should look](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2behHAueWIQ)

Here is the code:

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.PagerSnapHelper
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING


class PagerSnapAndSkipDividerHelper : PagerSnapHelper() {

    private var dx = 0

    override fun attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView?) {
        super.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
        recyclerView?.addOnScrollListener(onScrollListener)
    }

    override fun findTargetSnapPosition(
        layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager?,
        velocityX: Int,
        velocityY: Int
    ): Int = getNextNonDividerPosition(
        super.findTargetSnapPosition(layoutManager, velocityX, velocityY)
    )

    private fun getNextNonDividerPosition(position: Int) =
        if (position % 2 == 0) position else if (dx > 0) position + 1 else position - 1

    private val onScrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            this@PagerSnapAndSkipDividerHelper.dx = dx
        }

        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            if (listOf(SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING).contains(newState)) {
                val viewToSnapTo = findSnapView(recyclerView.layoutManager) ?: return
                val position = recyclerView.layoutManager?.getPosition(viewToSnapTo) ?: return
                val nonDividerPosition = getNextNonDividerPosition(position)
                if (position != nonDividerPosition) {
                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(nonDividerPosition)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Set it like this:

```
PagerSnapAndSkipDividerHelper().attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
```